# Change variable value on button click in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, css

below I have posted the code for my drop-down menu. At the very end, there is a variable called `variableToChange=""`.

Probably it is an easy question for the more experienced ones but I want every time I press some button to change the value of the variable. Let's say it should take the text of the button as a new value.

I guess it should be implemented somewhere into the `on click` part but I lack the experience here so I can't really implement it. I would really appreciate some help.

*Update*: Expected scenario would be: when I press the button called AA the value of variableToChange should be changed to "AA". Similarly, if I press afterwards BC it should be changed again to "BC".

```js
//How
const how_Tab = document.getElementById('a')
const how_tabName = how_Tab.querySelector('.tab-name')
const how_Links = document.querySelector('.how-links')

how_Tab.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const isOpen = how_Links.classList.contains('open')

  if (isOpen) how_Links.classList.remove('open')
  else how_Links.classList.add('open')
})

// link event listeners
const how_links = [...how_Links.children] // turn this into an array

how_links.forEach(how_link => how_link.addEventListener('click', e => {
  how_tabName.innerText = how_link.innerText

}))

//Type
const type_Tab = document.getElementById('b')
const type_tabName = type_Tab.querySelector('.tab-name')
const type_Links = document.querySelector('.type-links')

type_Tab.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const isOpen = type_Links.classList.contains('open')

  if (isOpen) type_Links.classList.remove('open')
  else type_Links.classList.add('open')
})

const type_links = [...type_Links.children] // turn this into an array

type_links.forEach(type_link => type_link.addEventListener('click', e => {
  type_tabName.innerText = type_link.innerText
}))

var variableToChange = "";
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #222;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 1000;
}

nav>* {
  flex: 1;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  height: 100%;
}

nav ul li {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  background: #222;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background: #555;
}

.how-links {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  /* This is the height of this div + height of the nav bar */
  transform: translateY(-135%);
  transition: 0.2s;
  z-index: -1;
}

.how-links.open {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.how-link {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s;
  background: #222;
  color: white;
}

.how-link:hover {
  background: #555;
}

.type-links {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  /* This is the height of this div + height of the nav bar */
  transform: translateY(-135%);
  transition: 0.2s;
  z-index: -1;
}

.type-links.open {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.type-link {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s;
  background: #222;
  color: white;
}

.type-link:hover {
  background: #555;
}

.markers-links {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  /* This is the height of this div + height of the nav bar */
  transform: translateY(-135%);
  transition: 0.2s;
  z-index: -1;
}

.markers-links.open {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.markers-link {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s;
  background: #222;
  color: white;
}

.markers-link:hover {
  background: #555;
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div id="root"></div>

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li id="a">
        <span class="tab-name"><i class="fa fa-eercast"></i>A</span>
        <div class="how-links">
          <a class="how-link" href="#">
            <option value="car"></option><i class="fa fa-car"></i>&nbsp;AA</a>
          <a class="how-link" href="#">
            <option value="bike"></option><i class="fa fa-road"></i>&nbsp;AB</a>
          <a class="how-link" href="#">
            <option value="foot"></option><i class="fa fa-paw"></i>&nbsp;AC</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li id="b">
        <span class="tab-name"><i class="fa fa-asterisk"></i>&nbsp;B</span>
        <div class="type-links">
          <a class="type-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-rocket"></i>&nbsp;BA</a>
          <a class="type-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-life-ring" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;BB</a>
          <a class="type-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-wifi"></i>&nbsp;BC</a>
          <a class="type-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>&nbsp;BD</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

</body>
```

Comment: what exactly do you mean by *but I want every time I press some button to change the value of the variable. Let's say it should take the text of the button as a new value.*

Comment: when I press the button called AA the value of `variableToChange` should be changed to "AA". Similarly if I press afterwards BC it should be changed again to "BC"

Comment: I'm not sure what's the issue. I've tried the fiddle and the dropdown works fine. Also, have you tried getting the value from how_tabName.innerText ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add

```
variableToChange = how_link.textContent.trim();
showValue.textContent = variableToChange // To show in the output
```

```js
//How
const showValue = document.querySelector("#showValue");
let variableToChange = "";
const how_Tab = document.getElementById('a')
const how_tabName = how_Tab.querySelector('.tab-name')
const how_Links = document.querySelector('.how-links')

how_Tab.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const isOpen = how_Links.classList.contains('open')

  if (isOpen) how_Links.classList.remove('open')
  else how_Links.classList.add('open')
})

// link event listeners
const how_links = [...how_Links.children] // turn this into an array

how_links.forEach(how_link => how_link.addEventListener('click', e => {
  how_tabName.innerText = how_link.innerText
  
  variableToChange = how_link.textContent.trim();  // CHANGE
  showValue.textContent = variableToChange
}))

//Type
const type_Tab = document.getElementById('b')
const type_tabName = type_Tab.querySelector('.tab-name')
const type_Links = document.querySelector('.type-links')

type_Tab.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const isOpen = type_Links.classList.contains('open')

  if (isOpen) type_Links.classList.remove('open')
  else type_Links.classList.add('open')
})

const type_links = [...type_Links.children] // turn this into an array

type_links.forEach(type_link => type_link.addEventListener('click', e => {
  type_tabName.innerText = type_link.innerText
  
  variableToChange = type_link.textContent.trim()  // CHANGE
  showValue.textContent = variableToChange
}))
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', sans-serif;
}

nav {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  background: #222;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  z-index: 1000;
}

nav>* {
  flex: 1;
}

nav ul {
  display: flex;
  list-style: none;
  height: 100%;
}

nav ul li {
  position: relative;
  flex: 1;
  background: #222;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background: #555;
}

.how-links {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  /* This is the height of this div + height of the nav bar */
  transform: translateY(-135%);
  transition: 0.2s;
  z-index: -1;
}

.how-links.open {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.how-link {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s;
  background: #222;
  color: white;
}

.how-link:hover {
  background: #555;
}

.type-links {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  /* This is the height of this div + height of the nav bar */
  transform: translateY(-135%);
  transition: 0.2s;
  z-index: -1;
}

.type-links.open {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.type-link {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s;
  background: #222;
  color: white;
}

.type-link:hover {
  background: #555;
}

.markers-links {
  position: absolute;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  left: 0;
  top: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  color: black;
  /* This is the height of this div + height of the nav bar */
  transform: translateY(-135%);
  transition: 0.2s;
  z-index: -1;
}

.markers-links.open {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.markers-link {
  height: 50px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  padding-left: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.2s;
  background: #222;
  color: white;
}

.markers-link:hover {
  background: #555;
}

#showValue {
  margin-top: 5rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>

<nav>
  <ul>
    <li id="a">
      <span class="tab-name"><i class="fa fa-eercast"></i>A</span>
      <div class="how-links">
        <a class="how-link" href="#">
          <option value="car"></option><i class="fa fa-car"></i>&nbsp;AA
        </a>
        <a class="how-link" href="#">
          <option value="bike"></option><i class="fa fa-road"></i>&nbsp;AB
        </a>
        <a class="how-link" href="#">
          <option value="foot"></option><i class="fa fa-paw"></i>&nbsp;AC
        </a>
      </div>
    </li>
    <li id="b">
      <span class="tab-name"><i class="fa fa-asterisk"></i>&nbsp;B</span>
      <div class="type-links">
        <a class="type-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-rocket"></i>&nbsp;BA</a>
        <a class="type-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-life-ring" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;BB</a>
        <a class="type-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-wifi"></i>&nbsp;BC</a>
        <a class="type-link" href="#"><i class="fa fa-leaf"></i>&nbsp;BD</a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>


<h5 id="showValue"></h5>
```